# Scrapy spider not crawling

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to test the scrapy CrawlSpider but I do not get why it's not crawling. What it should do is crawling the Mathematics page of wikipedia for only one depth level and return the header of each crawled page.  What do I miss? Help is very much appreciated!

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from Beurs.items import WikiItem

class WikiSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'WikiSpider'
    allowed_domains = ['wikipedia.org']
    start_urls = ["http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics"]

    Rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths=('//div[@class="mw-body"]//a/@href'))),
        Rule(LinkExtractor( allow=("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/",)),     callback='parse_item', follow=True),        
        )


def parse_item(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)  
    rows = sel.xpath('//span[@class="innhold"]/table/tr')
    items = []

        for row in rows[1:]:
            item = WikiItem()
            item['agent'] = row.xpath('./td[1]/a/text()|./td[1]/text()').extract()
            item['org'] = row.xpath('./td[2]/text()').extract()
            item['link'] = row.xpath('./td[1]/a/@href').extract()
            item['produkt'] = row.xpath('./td[3]/text()').extract()
        items.append(item)
        return items
```

settings:

```
BOT_NAME = 'Beurs'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['Beurs.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'Beurs.spiders'
DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS = {
  's3': None,
}
DEPTH_LIMIT = 1
```

and the log:

```
C:\Users\Jan Willem\Anaconda\Beurs>scrapy crawl BeursSpider
2015-11-07 15:14:36 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.3 started (bot: Beurs)
2015-11-07 15:14:36 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11,    boto
2015-11-07 15:14:36 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'Beurs.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['Beurs.spiders'], 'DEPTH_LIMIT': 1,    'BOT_NAME': 'Beurs'}
2015-11-07 15:14:36 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
2015-11-07 15:14:36 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2015-11-07 15:14:36 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2015-11-07 15:14:36 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
2015-11-07 15:14:36 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2015-11-07 15:14:36 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-11-07 15:14:36 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2015-11-07 15:14:36 [scrapy] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics> from <GET http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics>
2015-11-07 15:14:37 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics> (referer: None)
2015-11-07 15:14:37 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2015-11-07 15:14:37 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 530,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 60393,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/301': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 7, 14, 14, 37, 274000),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 7, 14, 14, 36, 852000)}
2015-11-07 15:14:37 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: So I changed the parsing part of the code in the one of Dup Step (see below), but I still get the same log of Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min). Somebody knows what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

So basically your regex wasn't quite right and your Xpath needed some tweaking. I think the code below fits your requirement so please try it out and let me know if you need any more help:

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    rows = sel.xpath('//span[@class="innhold"]/table/tr')
    items = []

    for row in rows[1:]:
        item = SasItem()
        item['agent'] = row.xpath('./td[1]/a/text()|./td[1]/text()').extract()
        item['org'] = row.xpath('./td[2]/text()').extract()
        item['link'] = row.xpath('./td[1]/a/@href').extract()
        item['produkt'] = row.xpath('./td[3]/text()').extract()
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I tried your tweaks but unfortunately didn't got it running. Still following issue:  Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min). It looks like the crawling itself is simply not happening and I can't figure out why. Any suggestions?